# « Caresser (l'espoir de...) » : entretenir avec « complaisance » ?

Tags: sens, étymologie, locutions, connotation

Je lis qu'une personne [*caresse l'espoir*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/caresser) de (quelque chose) et on me dit que ça signifie « entretenir avec [*complaisance*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/complaisance) (l'espoir de) » (TLFi).

---

La première acception au lexique pour *complaisance* serait le « désir de faire plaisir, d'être agréable, de rendre service à autrui » (TLFi), qui me fait un peu penser à la définition de l'[*altruisme*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/altruisme), par exemple en psychologie « disposition bienveillante à l'égard des autres, fondée sur la sympathie » (TLFi).

Ensuite on voit que le verbe [*caresser*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/caresser) provient d'un emprunt à l'italien pour *chérir* ; avec un complément de sens psychologique c'est attesté en 1736 pour « entretenir complaisamment » et on donne l'exemple avec *un projet* (DHLF, TLFi). Je pensais que la *complaisance* signifiait exclusivement le manque de rigueur, « l'indulgence blâmable » et c'est comme ça que je comprenais *abuser de la complaisance de quelqu'un*, non pas comme de sa *gentillesse*, mais simplement de son manque de rigueur par égard en contexte.

---

- Sur quel sens de *complaisance* s'appuie la définition de *caresser* en
  syntagme avec *espoir* etc. ; plus généralement peut-on confirmer que l'acception pour *gentillesse* déclasse en fréquence celle pour l'*indulgence blâmable* ?
- Est-ce par le truchement (étymologique) du verbe *chérir* qu'il faut comprendre *caresser* (l'espoir) : *il/elle chérissait l'espoir* ; le verbe *caresser* est-il simplement plus facile à prononcer que *chérir* au présent de l'indicatif ; en quoi serait-ce différent d'*avoir* (l'espoir) ?
- Y a-t-il une connotation négative, péjorative associée au syntagme, une idée de jugement, par exemple du caractère utopique de l'espoir, du projet, ou en ce qui a trait aux motivations de la personne qui entretient complaisamment (l'espoir) ?

Answer (score 4):

Du Trésor de la langue française :

> #### COMPLAISANCE, nf
>
> A) [Avec une idée d'intérêt porté à autrui]
>   1. Désir de faire plaisir, d'être agréable, de rendre service à autrui.
>   2. Soins attentifs, délicatesses. • [Dans des formules de politesse] Gentillesse, bonté, amabilité. • *Au plur., style biblique.* Affection, amour de Dieu
>   3. *Attestation, certificat de complaisance.* • *Billet, effet de complaisance.*
>   4. Actes d'indulgence et de soumission blâmable • [En parlant d'une femme] *Avoir des complaisances pour qqn.*
>   B) [Avec une idée d'intérêt porté à soi] Délectation, contentement, satisfaction.

De prime abord, parmi ces définitions, seules A1 & A2 semblent plausibles.

On peut écarter, ou discarter en bon québécois, A3 parce qu’il n’y a pas lieu de donner des papiers simili-légaux à un espoir ou à un rêve, pas plus qu’on ne doit ou peut mettre son nom en gage pour convaincre ce rêve ou cet espoir de notre bonne foi.

De même, il n’y a pas lieu de penser qu’un rêve puisse se matérialiser au point que l’on fasse la carpette devant, ou qu’on lui procure une quelconque satisfaction de la chair, pour quelque raison que se soit. A4 ne correspond pas.

Quant à B, ce genre de complaisance pourra s’établir chez certains, une fois le projet carressé accompli, mais tant que celui-ci appartient au futur, il n’y a pas lieu d’en retirer une fierté démesurée.

De A1 ou A2, lequel est le bon ? De quoi un espoir a-t-il besoin. Qu’on lui fasse plaisir, ou qu’on le maintienne dans la réalité ? Il me semble logique de penser que sa simple existence pourrait être précaire. Parfois, pour peu que l’on regarde la réalité en face, on se rend compte que la réalisation d’un rêve est chimérique et n’a aucune chance raisonnable de se concrétiser. Entretenir l’espoir, en le mettant temporairement de côté mais en continuant de réfléchir aux manières de contourner ou de surmonter les problèmes, me semble correspondre à une manière raisonnable de caresser un rêve, et coller d’assez près à la définition A2 :

> Soins attentifs, délicatesses.

---

#### CARESSER vs CHÉRIR

Bien que CARESSER provienne d’un mot italien signifiant *chérir*, il semble avoir inclus de tout temps en français un contact avec l’objet, du moins dans son sens propre, non-figuré.

Il va de soi que l’on s’occupe bien de quelque chose que l’on chérit, mais CARESSER est plus explicite et décrit exactement le genre d’attention conférée à ce qui est chéri, attention qui, du moins l’espère-t-on, lui donnera la force de résister encore et toujours aux aléas de la réalité.

Je crois donc, mais je suis peut-être naïf de le croire, que le verbe est adéquatement choisi, qu’il constitue un choix *un peu* meilleur que CHÉRIR.

---

#### Péjoratif ? Parfois, souvent, toujours ?

Si la pensée même de la chose caressée était inimaginable et qu’un événement inattendu modifie soudainement les possibles envisageables, on peut *« commencer à caresser l’espoir »* d’une certaine chose, sans que cela ne soit péjoratif le moindrement :

> Aujourd'hui, ce même général Lomakine, ces mêmes Cosaques devant lesquels on s'était incliné en tremblant, étaient dépouillés de leur pouvoir de fascination ; on les avait vus fuir, on avait assisté à leur désarroi, à leur effarement, à leur déroute, et **l’on commençait à caresser l’espoir** de les refouler au delà du lac d'Aral, au delà de la mer Caspienne, dans leurs montagnes de l'Oural et du Caucase.
>       —*L'Afghanistan : les Russes aux portes de l'Inde*, Charles SIMOND, 1885

Quand pour d’aucuns le rêve est accessible et bénin, mais que pour soi il est difficile et dangereux, on peut *« ne pas même oser caresser  l’espoir »* de ce rêve, sans que cela doive préjuger d’une capacité réduite de jugement ou d’action de la part de la personne n’osant pas.

Une personne aveugle ne serait pas ridicule de ne pas oser caresser l’espoir d’obtenir un permis de conduire (et la pratique du [ski alpin par cette personne](http://www.aslaa.org/piloter-un-deficient-visuel/) serait tout simplement digne de respect, même s’il s’agit d’une activité facilement praticable par la plupart des gens).

> Il était permis à d'autres d’espérer, mais lui **il n’osait pas caresser l’espoir** de revoir la France.
>       —*Mémoires*, Thomas Wiltberger EVANS, 1935

Si le rêve demeure encore possible, si son accomplissement demeure dans la sphère du plausible ou de l’imaginable, il n’est pas non plus risible de le caresser :

> Ils pouvaient **encore caresser l’espoir** d’un redoux, mais les températures hivernales étaient précoces et l’hiver s’annonçait rude.

De ce qui précède il paraît logique de conclure que l’expression n’est pas a priori péjorative. Pourrait-elle l’être ? De la part de quelqu’un qui s’accroche désespérément à un rêve hors d’atteinte, oui, ce pourrait l’être.

La manière la plus simple d’ajouter une connotation négative sera de l’accompagner d’un vocabulaire dépréciatif :

- **Oser** caresser l’espoir de...
- **Se permettre de** caresser l’espoir de...
- Caresser **une chimère**
- « **Comment peut-il** caresser l’espoir de... ? »
- Caresser l’espoir **invraisemblable/ridicule/extravagant/insolant** de...
- **Si, au lieu de** caresser l’espoir de [...], **ils faisaient/attendaient/travaillaient simplement**...

On pourra aussi croire que caresser un certain espoir est faire preuve de trop d’optimisme, à tous les degrés de débordement d’optimisme imaginables. La connotation négative s’ajuste alors au niveau d’optimisme inféré :

- *On peut se montrer prudent, si l’excès d’optimisme perçu est léger, voire sujet à caution :* On pourra arguer que caresser cet espoir, c’est être un peu trop optimiste sur la nature humaine.
- *...ou on peut se montrer beaucoup plus catégorique :* Nous devons conclure que seul un optimisme démesuré, insensé, que rien ne saurait justifier, que tous les arguments démontrent infondé et indéfendable, les font persister à caresser cet espoir.

Pourrait-on avoir une connotation négative sans le vocabulaire idoine, cependant ? Probablement. Si on perçoit un espoir qui est assez unanimement perçu comme irréaliste, sa simple mention invoque déjà un certain ridicule :

- Ces gens caressent l’espoir de prouver hors de tout doute raisonnable que la Terre est plate.
- À 45 ans, il caresse encore l’espoir de gagner le Tour de France.

On pourrait aussi, en parlant d’un espoir impossible, affirmer *« qu’il ne faut pas caresser l’espoir de... »*. Cela tend à rendre ridicule la caresse de cet espoir en particulier, mais ne confère en aucune manière un statut ridicule à toute entreprise de caresse d’espoir, et ne préjuge pas non plus forcément de ceux qui jusqu’alors auraient pu l’entretenir.

**Péjoratif, alors ?** Je dirais que dans la plupart des cas, **non**. La tournure se prête assez bien à l’expression du ridicule, oui, mais n’est pas foncièrement, intrinsèquement attachée à la notion de ridicule.

Comment: +1 globalement. Pour la blague : Ainsi vous "*discartez*" ? Bien que je vous sache ici entre vous... hmmm... mon hexagonalisme sursaute... ;-) . Cela dit sur le fond je m'accorde sauf, peut-être, relativement à votre dernière partie relativement à ce que je tiens pour une **perception**. Analyse restreinte à l'extrait de Simond, je serais curieux de savoir ce qui **vous** fait penser à une absence de sarcasme. Pour le détail, je ne m'accorde pas vraiment **ici** à votre usage de *catégorique* mais peut-être avez-vous raison de l'utiliser ainsi.

Comment: @aCOSwt Entendu pour discarter. Je réviserai sous peu, lorsque l’inspiration m’aura visité. L’extrait de Simond, c'est une idée que *«l’espoir apparaît, que l’on commence à croire que quelque chose devient possible, qu’on ose y penser comme quelque chose d’atteignable»*. Je n’y vois pas de sarcasme, ce qui suffit à me faire dire que l’on est pas **forcé** d’y voir un sarcasme.

Comment: @aCOSwt Quant à *catégorique*, je voulais simplement indiquer que l’on peut, comme dans mon exemple, se montrer très convaincu de la valeur de notre évaluation du débordement d’optimisme, et faire des affirmations catégoriques. Sans doute mon approche et ma présentation demeurent-elles floues, en dépit de ma bonne volonté et de ma tentative de m’inspirer librement du modèle du sieur Edmond Rostand *(En variant le ton, — par exemple, tenez)*. Je vais tenter de régler ce petit problème. Merci de vos commentaires.

Comment: Finalement, j’opte pour *écarter*, mais *discarter* est si commun depuis tant de générations au Québec que j’ai décidé de le maintenir à ses côtés, espérant que par cette promiscuité il puisse obtenir un peu du prestige de son voisin, comme le fit [le renard aux dépents du tigre](https://chine.in/guide/renard-tigre_386.html)...

Comment: Yop! +1 pour le *si je ne suis pas forcé de comprendre un second degré alors je ne le prends pas ainsi* Yess! Absolument! Ça le fait. Toutefois... je trouve cela un peu facilité par le fait que nous lisons postérieurement à l'épreuve des faits. Postérieurement à la réalisation de l'espoir. Ce qui, en tant qu'espoir, lui confère (je trouve) valeur et crédibilité. Si, au contraire, ce même texte est une chronique que je lis au jour du jour des événements et que par surcroît, je suis ou tiens l'auteur pour pro-soviétique, je lirais nécessairement un sarcasme. Perception... perception.

Comment: Pro-soviétique en [1885](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovi%C3%A9tiques)? Perception, perception... en effet! :~)

Comment: lol! j'ai écrit celà ? Moi ? Ha oui! Tiens... Bon!... Allez! Même ce bon Homère s'endort parfois... à ce qu'on assure... Mais vous aurez corrigé de vous-même je présume. Pro-Russe évidemment. Il n'empêche! Le point est pour vous! ;-)

Comment: Ha! Je comprends d'une de vos dernières contributions que vous avez pris mon observation sur *discarter* en mauvaise part. Je vous prie alors de m'en excuser et vous assure qu'il n'y avait nulle malice dans ma remarque... *pour la blague*. De fait, j'adore les non-hexagonalismes.

Comment: @aCOSwt Pas du tout. Ce n'était pas une première pour moi, et ce ne sera sûrement pas la dernière.

Answer (score 3):

**A/ De *complaisance* en général**

1/ Puisque vous citez le TLF, vous aurez noté qu'au sens d'indulgence blâmable, il ne s'agit que d'un emploi *péjoratif, par métonymie et le plus souvent au pluriel.* Ce qui, à mon sens, revient à dire qu'il est plus rare.

2/ Il est assez difficile d'obtenir immédiatement des données objectives de fréquence de signification.
Je le fais pour ma part en comptant les [cliques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28th%C3%A9orie_des_graphes%29) sur un graphe représentant un corpus d'environ 50K mots extraits avec leur sens (représenté par un synonyme) d'un corpus de référence. <sup>1</sup>

Ce comptage donne ici un score de 30 pour *amabilité*, 30 pour *prévenance*, 26 pour *gentillesse*, 24 pour *bienveillance*, 18 pour *amitié*, 18 pour *obligeance*, 15 pour *tendresse*, 14 pour *faveur*, 13 pour *indulgence*...

Je déduirais donc de ce comptage que, même en cumulant les scores de *faveur* et d'*indulgence*, les sens d'*amabilité*... *gentillesse* devancent significativement.

Ces deux points concourent à me laisser penser que l'indulgence blâmable est effectivement *déclassée*.
Mais encore une fois, corpus, corpus... je ne fais pas de doute que pour qui ne compilerait que les chroniques judiciaires ou administratives ou chienécrasesques... il en irait à l'opposé.

**B/ Du sens de complaisance dans la définition du TLF pour caresser ?**

Bhein... là... il faudrait demander au lexicaliste concerné. Et je crains... qu'il ne soit plus. Donc...
Maintenant L'Académie disant ***se complaire*** dans... puis, pour *se complaire : Se délecter, trouver son plaisir, sa satisfaction*, je crois que l'on peut sans se tromper oublier l'indulgence blâmable.

**C/ Comprendre caresser par le truchement de chérir, chérir plus difficile à prononcer ?**

Si on en croit l'article du TLF, je n'ai pas vraiment l'impression que la prononciation de *caresser* ait semblé des plus évidentes non plus.

Maintenant, l'argument de l'élégance / facilité de conjugaison peut effectivement être un argument pour la préférence de *caresser* sur non pas *chérir* mais bien plutôt : **Choyer**! Vous observerez au demeurant que la définition qu'en donne le [TLF (B)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/choyer) est quasi identique.

Je crois donc que, de façon plus immédiate qu'avec *chérir*, c'est par le truchement de *choyer* que l'on peut comprendre *caresser*.

**D/ Sa différence avec *avoir*,**

je la crois tout simplement logique. Elle tient au simple fait que l'espoir est une abstraction et qu'on ne peut formellement *avoir* ce genre de truc. Sans compter que ce verbe est dénué de tout **affect**, denrée qui me semble primordiale dans *chérir, choyer, caresser*.

**E/ Connotation négative ?**

La lecture péjorante / négative / critique... est toujours de la responsabilité... du lecteur! C'est **vous** qui la mettez... ou pas! Ce genre de **charge** est toujours laissé à l'implicite, c'est à dire, à la liberté de lecture.
L'auteur l'y a mise cette charge ? Lisez autour. Comprenez du contexte s'il est moqueur ou non, affectueux ou non, critique ou complice... ce sera donc... selon.

Sur ce, il est l'heure! Je m'en vais, pour ma part caresser... la bouteille! ;-)

---

<sub>1 : Pour des utilisations à des fins statistiques c'est toujours là que le bât blesse tant évidemment, la définition d'un corpus étant toujours soumise à l'arbitraire difficilement soluble dans le nombre quel qu'il soit... La dernière mise à jour du mien remonte à l'an dernier, les données que j'en tire ici sont donc relativement actualisées.</sub>